# Style display = block?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have very strange situation :) My question is when open the page user see only dropdrown list .After choose options all div hidden .Can make when is choose  the div shows after submit :)

JSP:

```
    <label id="ShowPosesConfig" >Configuration</label><br/>

<div id="DivPosesConfig" class="DivPosesConfig" style="display:none">
enter code here
     <form action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/UpdateServlet" method="post" name="nomPosInfo" id="posesAction">


          <select onchange="return checkSelect();">
             <option value="-1">Please choose ...</option>
              <% for(PosesBean poses : posesMap.values()){%>
                <option <%=poses.getPosID()== selectedId ? "selected" : ""%> value="<%=poses.getPosID()%>"><%=poses.getPosCode()+ " "%><%=poses.getAddressBG()%></option>
              <%}%>
           </select><br/><br/><br/>


           <%if(selectedId > -1){%>
            <label>Email:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" id="emailPos" name="email" value="<%=selectedId == -1 ? "" : posesMap.get(selectedId).getEmail()%>"  size="45"/><br/><br/>

            <label>Phone:</label>&nbsp;<input type="text" id="phonePos" name="phone" value="<%=selectedId == -1 ? "" : posesMap.get(selectedId).getPhone()%>"  size="45" /><br/><br/>


            <input type="submit" style="margin-left:125px"  value="Save changes" onclick="return checkRadio();"/><br/><br/>
            <hr class="order"/><br/>
            <%}%>
     </form>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#ShowPosesConfig').click(function(){
           $('.DivPosesConfig').toggle("fast");
        });
 });
```

Comment: its not clear,so whats the problem?

Comment: Can you post what the HTML looks like *after* the JSP has been parsed and sent to the browser? You can right click the page in your browser and choose "View Source" or "View Page Source" (or similar, it depends on the browser) to see the HTML at this point (after server has processed it, but without any parsing and JavaScript execution done by the browser).

Comment: When the page is loaded user see only dropdown list ,after select someone option page is submit and after that i want the div shows.
Now the user must click on the label to see the div

Comment: Just make that `style="display:none"` conditional in the jsp?